# How to create a docker image with passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, passenger

I'm trying to create a docker image with a rails app and passenger.
I have read this article : https://intercityup.com/blog/how-i-build-a-docker-image-for-my-rails-app.html

It works good, gems are well installed, but when I call the app, I have this error :

> Message from application: libruby.so.2.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/app/webapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/pg-0.18.3/pg_ext.so (LoadError)

And when I'm connecting to the image, the file /home/app/webapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/pg-0.18.3/pg_ext.so really exists.

So I don't understand what happened.

My docker file :

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby21:0.9.12
MAINTAINER Eric L'Hostis "eric.lhostis@gmail.com"

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# Conf Nginx / Passenger
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf

# Prepare folders
RUN mkdir /home/app/webapp
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile /tmp/
ADD Gemfile.lock /tmp/
RUN bundle install

# Add the rails app
ADD . /home/app/webapp
```

And to create/run the image.

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker run -d -p 80:80 myimage
```

I have already trying to install these libs : libpq-dev, nodejs, build-essential, postgresql
without success :(

Comment: have you checked the privileges for this file or a folder? We had like the same issue, then we could not start our server, which was added into the image via dockerfile, because it had wrong privileges.

Comment: I guess some third party libraries (probably dependencies of pg_ext.so) are missing

Comment: Privileges are good @Stanislav. I have only the root user.

Comment: The same project works good in a "standalone" mode. So what third party can be necessary ?

Comment: Can you add your dockerfile and run command?

Comment: I was wondering if at the end you found a stable recipe. I'd love to try it out.

Comment: @a.barbieri, no I don't find stable recipe. But it was one year ago. Maybe, it's fixed now with the new versions of passenger. I don't know

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you're using postgres as database and you are missing `libpq-dev` in your image.

I don't use passenger when deploying rails apps with docker, but I think you should check if the lib is installed.

You could just try to add:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```

in your `DOCKERFILE` to install the lib.

or even better:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get clean
```

If you wan't your image to be as small as possible.

**Side note:**

In my opinion the base image you're using contains huge overhead. When working with docker my images are usually less than 400 MB. The base image you use is ~960 MB. You should check whether you could use `:latest` as it's way smaller (~211 MB).

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't work. This lib is still installed : "libpq-dev is already the newest version". So, same error then.